# Where to discuss Software Design Patterns?

Tags: discussion, site-rec

Stack Exchange is for question with a clear answer. But I want to discuss Software Design Pattern.

I could not find a matching discussion group.

Where can I find a group/forum/mailinglist to discuss Software Design Patterns?

Comment: You'd be better off formulating an actual question.  If you just want to discuss, read Fowler's book or his blog.  He has plenty of discussion about software patterns there.

Comment: Ward Cunningham invented [the wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki) specifically as a discussion platform for design patterns. To this day, that's where a lot of DP discussion happens.